# Cannot create procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create following procedure that I exported from different server but getting an error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spGetWorkHistoryByEmployeeID`(pEmployeeID int, pStartIndex int, pCount int)
BEGIN   
    DECLARE LowerBound  INT;  
    DECLARE UpperBound  INT;  
    DECLARE rownum  INT;  
    SET LowerBound = ((pStartIndex - 1) * pCount) + 1;
    SET UpperBound = ((pStartIndex - 1) * pCount) + pCount;

SELECT 
    rank, JobNumber, EarliestDate, LatestDate, BillableHours
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        j.JobNumber, s.EarliestDate, s.LatestDate, s.BillableHours
    FROM
        service s
    LEFT JOIN Job j ON s.JobID = j.JobID
    WHERE
        s.EmployeeAssignedID = pEmployeeID 
            AND s.LatestDate < NOW()
    ORDER BY s.LatestDate DESC) d, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r) m
WHERE
    rank >= LowerBound
        AND rank <= UpperBound;
END
```

Error says: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank     FROM         ( SELECT          j.JobNumber, s.EarliestDate, s.LatestDat' at line 2`

MySql Workbench is showing wiggle under the first `SELECT` with tooltip of `"SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting '(', WITH`

It is MySql Community Server 8.0.12 for what is matter.

Any idea what is wrong? the procedure exist on different server and working well.

UPDATE: problem solved! apparently starting v.8.0.2  `RANK` is reserved word. 
The server I copied the db from is older version. Thank you @Nick!

Comment: `rank` is a reserved word

Comment: @Nick I renamed `rank` to `rank1` and still same result

Comment: The same error in the same place? If you change them all to `rank1` it compiles fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2012c079d11be1bed7c35b30e574217e

Comment: oh sorry - seems like i missed one `rank` in where clause. error is gone. write it as an answer so I can accept it